# making sure all checkboxes are checked when button is pressed

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am looking to validate all checkboxes which are shown in the model dialog when a user clicks on the `Agreed` button.

Here's my code:

```js
$( function() {
    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
      resizable: true,
      height: "auto",
      width: "80%",
      modal: true,
      title:"Select everything",
        classes: {
        'ui-dialog':'my-custom-dialog'
      },
      buttons: {
        "Agreed": function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
          var countCheckBoxes = 0;

          var countCheckBoxesSelected = 0;
          for (i = 0; i < document.forms[0].elements.length; i++) {
          if (document.forms[0].elements[i].type == 'checkbox') {
          countCheckBoxes++;
              if (document.forms[0].elements[i].checked) {
              countCheckBoxesSelected++;
              }
            }
          }

          if (countCheckBoxes == countCheckBoxesSelected) {
            alert("OK - to save");
            } else {
            alert("All checkboxes must be checked first.");
          }
},
        Cancel: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
    });
  } );
```

```css
.ui-dialog.my-custom-dialog {
  left:0!important;
  right:0!important;
  margin:auto;
}

.ui-dialog.my-custom-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane .ui-dialog-buttonset{
  float:none;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Modal confirmation</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <script>
  
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="dialog-confirm" >
 
  <input type="checkbox" id="check1" name="vehicle1" value="Bike">
  <label for="vehicle1"> I have a bike</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle2" name="vehicle2" value="Car">
  <label for="vehicle2"> I have a car</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle3" name="vehicle3" value="Boat">
  <label for="vehicle3"> I have a boat</label><br><br>
</div>
 
<p>Sed vel diam id libero <a href="http://example.com">rutrum convallis</a>. Donec aliquet leo vel magna. Phasellus rhoncus faucibus ante. Etiam bibendum, enim faucibus aliquet rhoncus, arcu felis ultricies neque, sit amet auctor elit eros a lectus.</p>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

But the solution that I was testing inside the `Agreed` button can't be used here as I can't use form here since my dialog code is already inside a form (not shown here) with other checkboxes on the form. So I'm looking for a way to make sure all checkboxes are checked once user hits `Agreed` button.

Comment: If you can't use form, then what have you tried instead?

Comment: I'm not sure what other options are available.

Comment: Or I could probably use form and use a specific ID to evaluate checkboxes for this particular form?

Comment: or replace the form in the js with their container.

Comment: ` replace the form in the js with their container` Not sure if I'm following you

Comment: instead of `document.forms[0].elements`, use the checkboxes' container, `document.querySelector("div#dialog-confirm")`.

Comment: `id="check1" name="vehicle1"` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the `$("#dialog-confirm")` selector, you just need to save that as a variable and then look for checkboxes inside of that.  Also jQuery selectors make minding checkboxes and checked checkboxes pretty easy, so you can take advantage of that instead of doing loops.

```js
$(function() {
  const $dialogConfirm = $("#dialog-confirm");
  const $checkboxes = $dialogConfirm.find(":checkbox");
  
  $dialogConfirm.dialog({
    resizable: true,
    height: "auto",
    width: "80%",
    modal: true,
    title:"Select everything",
      classes: {
      'ui-dialog':'my-custom-dialog'
    },
    buttons: {
      "Agreed": function() {
        const $checkedCheckboxes = $checkboxes.filter(":checked")

        if ($checkboxes.length === $checkedCheckboxes.length) {
          console.log("OK - to save");
          $dialogConfirm.dialog("close");
        } else {
          console.log("All checkboxes must be checked first.");
        }
      },
      Cancel: function() {
        $dialogConfirm.dialog("close");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.ui-dialog.my-custom-dialog {
  left:0!important;
  right:0!important;
  margin:auto;
}

.ui-dialog.my-custom-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane .ui-dialog-buttonset{
  float:none;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="dialog-confirm" >
 
  <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle1" name="vehicle1" value="Bike">
  <label for="vehicle1"> I have a bike</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle2" name="vehicle2" value="Car">
  <label for="vehicle2"> I have a car</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle3" name="vehicle3" value="Boat">
  <label for="vehicle3"> I have a boat</label><br><br>
</div>
 
<p>Sed vel diam id libero <a href="http://example.com">rutrum convallis</a>. Donec aliquet leo vel magna. Phasellus rhoncus faucibus ante. Etiam bibendum, enim faucibus aliquet rhoncus, arcu felis ultricies neque, sit amet auctor elit eros a lectus.</p>
```

Comment: Thanks. So `const $checkboxes = $dialogConfirm.find(":checkbox");` is storing all the checkboxes count in the variable ` $checkboxes` ? As I see that you are using `$checkboxes. length` for comparison later on.

Comment: `$checkboxes` are all of the checkboxes as an array. so `$checkboxes.length` is how many items are in that array.  Then `$checkboxes.filter(":checked")` is saved to another variable when the button is pressed, this will take the array of `$checkboxes` and filter that array down to only include the ones that are checked.  So if the number of items in both arrays are equal, all the checkboxes are checked!